# Convert from windows .dmp to linux core file

Tags: converters, coredump, google-breakpad

I am using google break pad to generate core dumps of linux applications. What I want to know is is there a way to convert from the .dmp that break pad creates to a linux core file, so that I can debug it with gdb and linux symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool in google break pad at /srs/tools/linux/md2core that does exactly this.